# JavaScript and HTML with dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I'm working on a dropdown with javascript. My HTML does not work and I can't find the problem... I think I've done right but maybe it's the link who does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("article.hey > *:not(header)").hide();
  $("article.hey header").on("click", function() {
    $(this).nextAll("*").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <article class="hey">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac metus quis ante elementum tristique sit amet quis lorem. Fusce placerat dignissim nunc vitae consequat. In sagittis velit vitae erat faucibus, vitae condimentum risus luctus. Aliquam
      consequat est pellentesque viverra hendrerit. Duis tincidunt mi sem, et rhoncus ante consequat id. Sed ex est, pulvinar et mi eu, placerat tincidunt lacus. Praesent congue turpis mi, at vestibulum
    </p>
  </article>
</header>
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the dropdown?

Comment: what doesn't work? What link may be not working? What exactly are you going to achieve (that for sure is not a dropdown)

Comment: IT's actually not a dropdown. I don't know how to say it. It's when you click on the header, the text should drop down.. Hope you understand! :)

Comment: ... and when you click again, it should close

Comment: `header` is parent of `article.hey` but you used `$("article.hey header")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your HTML must be the `header` tag inside the `article` tag:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("article.hey > *:not(header)").hide();
  $("article.hey header").on("click", function() {
    $(this).nextAll("*").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="hey">
  <header>I'm the header 'CLICK ME'</header>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac metus quis ante elementum tristique sit amet quis lorem. Fusce placerat dignissim nunc vitae consequat. In sagittis velit vitae erat faucibus, vitae condimentum risus luctus. Aliquam
    consequat est pellentesque viverra hendrerit. Duis tincidunt mi sem, et rhoncus ante consequat id. Sed ex est, pulvinar et mi eu, placerat tincidunt lacus. Praesent congue turpis mi, at vestibulum
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So the article will be the parent. Now i understand!